# Retrofit: How do I go about downloading images? + Some other questions

Tags: android, retrofit

I am currently looking into implementing the Retrofit API (after using Volley) into my app and I have some questions that I cannot seem to find answers to anywhere else so I will ask here.

1. How do I go about downloading images using Retrofit API? I am asking this because Volley has the ImageLoader class and NetworkedImageView etc. and was wondering if Retrofit has something similar?

   2. I read that using the RequestIntercepter, it can add a header to every request. How is this different from just adding a static (or dynamic) header (@Header) in the interface's abstract method
   3. How does Retrofit deal with nested JSON objects? I read it uses GSON to convert the JSON into java objects but the POJO class must have the same field names.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your first doubt:**

**Retrofit** no have feature to manager image as `Volley` and UIL has. The same company that developer Retrofit too have a nice lib to manager images called [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

**For your second doubt:**

> Headers that need to be added to every request can be specified using
>   a RequestInterceptor. The following code creates a RequestInterceptor
>   that will add a User-Agent header to every request.

for instance:

I developed a client to [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) and to all request I need set my keys in the header: see here [Android-Retrofit-Example](https://github.com/andersonacs/Android-Retrofit-Example)

```
public class RestClient {

    private static RestClient mRestClient = null;
    private static RestAdapter restAdapter;
    private static RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    public static RestClient getInstance(){

        if(mRestClient == null ){

            mRestClient = new RestClient();
            setup();
        }

        return mRestClient;
    }

    private static void setup(){

        requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {

                request.addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "");
                request.addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "");
            }
        };

        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(" https://api.parse.com/1/")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .build();
    }

    public RestAdapter getRestAdapter(){
        return restAdapter;
    }
}
```

The last :

JSON CONVERSION

> Retrofit uses Gson by default to convert HTTP bodies to and from JSON.
>   If you want to specify behavior that is different from Gson's defaults
>   (e.g. naming policies, date formats, custom types), provide a new Gson
>   instance with your desired behavior when building a RestAdapter. Refer
>   to the Gson documentation for more details on customization.

To get this :

```
{
results: [3]
        {
            createdAt: "2015-03-07T20:43:44.107Z"
            objectId: "osCJ8PI65r"
            updatedAt: "2015-03-08T00:45:37.539Z"
            username: "Test 2"
        },
        {
            createdAt: "2015-03-07T21:42:38.591Z"
            objectId: "tkIi6Ll1Os"
            updatedAt: "2015-03-07T21:42:38.591Z"
            username: "Test 2"
        },
        {
            createdAt: "2015-03-08T01:13:21.188Z"
            objectId: "Cz0HqiYpwl"
            updatedAt: "2015-03-08T04:21:18.069Z"
            username: "Test 3"
        }
}
```

Pojo :

```
public class User {

    private String objectId;
    private String username;
    private String createdAt;
    private String updatedAt;

    //gerate getters and setters
}

public class WrappeUser {

    @SerializedName(value="results")
    List<User> results;

    public List<User> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<User> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. In the github example you provided, is there a reason why in the MainActivity the call to the service occurs on a separate thread (async task) I thought the network tasks were by default on a separate thread but the call back occurs on the main thread?

Comment: Retrofit methods can be declared for either synchronous or asynchronous execution. Asynchronous execution requires the last parameter of the method be a callback  that will be executed on the main thread =)

Comment: Thanks. One more question. How would you handle deeply nested JSON objects? Would it be better to just get the raw JSON and do it yourself? The JSON data I have has a lot of nested objects with objects in objects :S